# Alternate Import Syntax in Go

Tags: go, import

I'd like to import stuff in Go files like so:

```
import "godotenv"
```

instead of the typical:

```
import "github.com/joho/godotenv"
```

I know this isn't the standard method, but I'm of the opinion that it's a cleaner syntax with much better maintainability.  I certainly don't mean to start an argument on the issue, but I've been searching quite a while and I'm hoping there's some way to accomplish this.

I think something like import maps in deno (https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/import_maps) seem like a reasonable compromise and I'd be happy to declare my "aliases" for imports in a separate file somewhere.  Is there any way for me to accomplish this?  I've tried the Go replace directive in go.mod, but that doesn't seem to be the replace directive's intent and doesn't seem to do what I'm trying to here.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is no mechanism that's intended to do what you want. This is not just about syntax. Import path are used by the go tool to locate and retrieve the packages required to build the program.

Comment: I think I understand, though I do think there's a way the go tooling could do something like deno import maps I mentioned.  Judging by the responses thus far though, it seems like that's not something that Go folks want.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Run the compiler directly instead of using `go build` and friends.  Specify an import map when compiling. This is a big task and I don’t recommend it.   See https://golang.org/cmd/compile/.

Comment: Thanks very much Cerise.  I was able to use go tool compile and go tool link to build a simple executable and was then able to modify it to work with imports as I described above.  It is indeed a bigger task than should probably be taken on for projects of any size, but you definitely answered my question.

For any others wanting to try this, the command "go build -x main.go" was very helpful in figuring things out.  It prints out all the commands run by go build, so you can emulate as needed.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to import stuff in Go files like so [...]

It does not matter at all what you like. What matters is the way you have to do it. Get used the the normal way.

You cannot do this.